# Load domain instances from m:n relationship in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, model

**Background:**

Consider the following model:

- A Map can be in one or more Mapsets
- A Mapset must contain one or  more Maps

I've modeled it like this:

`Map.groovy`:

```
static belongsTo = [ User, Mapset ]
static hasMany = [ mapsets : Mapset ]
```

`Mapset.groovy`:

```
static hasMany = [ maps : Map ]
```

---

**Problem:**

I'm in the Map controller, and I have a parameter named `set`, which designates the set I want to load the maps from.

Normally, my Map controller loads the maps and shows them on a paginated view, like this:

```
def maps = Map.createCriteria().list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset, sort: params.sort, order: params.order) { }
```

But in order to be more selective, I'd only like to get the maps that belong to one Mapset.

**Question:**

How do I load only the maps that belong to the Mapset with `id = 1`? I need the pagination parameters though.

I figured I could do something like that:

```
Mapset.get(params.set).maps
```

but what then?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]

```
def maps = Map.createCriteria().list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset, sort: params.sort, order: params.order){
   mapsets {
       eq('id', params.set)
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `No property found for name [mapset] for class [Map]` - because a map can belong to several sets.

Comment: How can you access the map's mapset? Try to be more specific in the belongsTo statement (static belongsTo = [user:User, mapset:Mapet]).

Comment: Hm.. when I do that, the app doesn't even run anymore: `No owner defined between domain classes [class Mapset] and [class Map] in a many-to-many relationship.`

Comment: I'm sorry , now I got it. I have updated my answer, but I have not a Grails setup at the moment so I'm not 100% confident it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the update! However, now it gets cryptic: `Executing action [browse] of controller [MapController] caused exception: java.lang.String`, without any further information..

Comment: Yes, pretty cryptic. I'm sorry I couldn't help you more without a working Grails env, I'm quite sure that the posted code should work, I did lots of complex criterias in Grails in the past. Last error looks like an conversion issue with the parameters (integer expected).

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help! I wonder though how something so basic can be so hard to accomplish?

Comment: You need to convert `params.set` to Long: `Long.valueOf(params.set)`